# How do I get the scroll position from Microsoft Excel

Tags: c#, automation, ms-office

When using Microsoft office automation I want to insert images into a spreadsheet.  How can I determine the current users scroll location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel you may use the VisibleRange property of the Window object, i.e.

```
Private Sub DirtyTest()
Dim MyW As Window, TopRow As Long, TopCol As Long

    Set MyW = Windows(1)                ' index 1 always refers to the window displayed
    TopRow = MyW.VisibleRange.Cells.Row
    TopCol = MyW.VisibleRange.Cells.Column

    ' any other code

End Sub
```

Hope that helps

Good luck MikeD